# How are representations of fermions and bosons made for different gauge groups?

Tags: representation-theory, fermions, grand-unification

I have been told to that representations(for particle physics) go like this:
How many versions or charges of a particle can be changed from a group's associated gauge interaction

In the standard model ($SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$), left-handed quarks have 3 colour charges ($SU(3)$) and can change between 2 isospins ($SU(2)$). So, its representation is $(3,2)_{1/3}$. The 1/3 is its weak hypercharge ($U(1)$).

Moving on to the Pati-Salam model ($SU(4) \times SU(2) \times SU(2)$). It has only 2 representations of fermions, $(4,2,1)$ and $(4,1,2)$. One for left handed and one for right handed fermions.

Next is the Georgi-Glashow model. This is where I see something new. Its representations of fermions are, $10$ and $5$ and $1$. If I look into the fermion content(which is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgi%E2%80%93Glashow_model#Explicit_Embedding_of_the_Standard_Model_(SM))) we get,

[image: 5]

and

[image: 10]

I realised how could 10 be a representation of $SU(5)$? Why is it in a matrix? And, what will the interaction term be (Since the generators of $SU(5)$ are $5 \times 5$ matrices) and is the solution to this is general such that similar solutions can be used for other representations?

Comment: *we get … and …* Your images aren’t displaying.

Comment: When you study these models, you appreciate the constraints imposed by consistency on them, and how they contain the SM. They are not "completely random", but you are asking for a tutorial on the logic of the models, which it behooves you to read about, so as to understand. Read up on Slansky's review article.

Comment: Sorry for the 3 month delay @Ghoster. However, I have fixed the issue now.

Comment: It seems your question really is about group and representation theory. You should probably check one of the available books or lecture notes on this, and then most of your question will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Physical observables should be color neutral (aka white). Colours do not represent any conserved charges because gauge invariance is a redundancy, not a physical symmetry. Gauge transformations are do-nothing transformations in the Hilbert space, and physical observables should be invariant under gauge transformations. The gauge group acting on the Hilbert space as a trivial representation.

Comment: Gauge invariance is only a redundancy when the bundle is trivial. It carries global physical information otherwise.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Can you give me any references? Thanks.

Comment: Look up relevant entries in NLab.